# Can I destructure an instance of a class in Dart? Not an array of primitives, but an object:

Tags: dart, destructuring

For example, an instance of the following class:

```
class ScanModel {
    ScanModel({
        this.id,
        this.tipo,
        required this.valor,
    });

    int? id;
    String? tipo;
    String valor;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want?

Comment: The dart language team is planning to pattern matching to a future version of dart. Pattern matching would allow you to destructure an instance of any class. There is a video discussing the upcoming feature https://youtu.be/KhYTFglbF2k?t=805